# Getting an empty response when calling CouchDB over ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB, so please bear with me.

I have an instance of CouchDB running on a VM. I can access it just fine through the browser via futon or directly at:

```
http://192.168.62.128:5984/articles/hot_dog
```

Calling that URL in a browser returns the proper JSON. But, when I try to call that exact same URL via ajax, I get nothing:

```
var ajaxUrl = 'http://192.168.62.128:5984/articles/hot_dog';
$.getJSON(ajaxUrl, null, function(data) { alert(data); });
```

Looking at the response header with Firebug shows me that the HTTP response was `200` and the `content-length` is the right size. Even the `Etag` matches with what is in CouchDB. But the response itself is *empty*!

The URL is absolutely right; I've triple checked, and copy/pasted it directly (and besides it wouldn't give a 200 response if it weren't). I'm using jQuery 1.4.2, and CouchDB 0.8

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds very strongly like you're trying to make a cross-domain AJAX request, which the browser will reject. To get around this, you can use JSONP like the answer above, but this will restrict you to GET requests; you won't be able to add, modify, or delete records.

If you are trying to do cross-domain AJAX calls with CouchDB, I recommend checking out this library:

http://github.com/benvinegar/couchdb-xd

Comment: You are absolutely right that it was a cross-domain issue. I ended up using a library called CouchApp to wrap all my code up into attachments in the couchdb, thus no more cross-domain issue. I'll take a peek at your library though too.

Since you are 'more' correct than jitter (and he has karma to spare :-p) I marked your response as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try appending `callback=?` to the url like this. This will trigger jQuery to issue a jsonp request.

```
var ajaxUrl = 'http://192.168.62.128:5984/articles/hot_dog?callback=?';
```

If this doesn't fix it additionally you should append a sample output of the json this url gives in the browser.

Comment: Ok, this combined with upgrading to couch 0.10.1 did the trick. Thank you! I still don't know why this happens though... why doesn't the ajax call work without the ?callback=? suffix?

Comment: From what you wrote in the question I assume that it isn't a cross-domain request problem (served by a webserver inside (with different port) or outside the vm both would count as cross-domain request and should be blocked by the browser). Adding the `callback` stuff makes it a `jsonp` request and basically this was just a guess, I'm not familiar with CouchDB so no idea why it doesn't work with a plain json request if cross-domain doesn't apply. As you mentioned the "upgrade" I noticed (googled) that jsonp support only came with version 0.10, so the upgrade was the right thing to do

Answer (score 5):

As you try to get the data from an other web server as your html file comes you need to do a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) query. First of all in the latest version of CouchDB you need to enable JSONP querys in the configuration (.ini) file. (It is disable by default since CouchDB 1.0) In the section [httpd] you need to add an

> allow_jsonp = true

After this is done you can produce JSONP queries on your CouchDB.

In jQuery then you have to add ?callback=? to the URL to trigger a JSONP query.

Happy Cross-Origin Resource Sharing everyone.

Comment: Why is jsonp always the answer for cors issues? Its an ok short term solution but for good REST practices never really a good long term one.

Comment: Agree with Justin, CORS is getting ludicrous. But loomi: how can the CouchDB server 'allow' jsonp? It doesn't know what the browser is using to do the request - jsonp is just a GET. Or does that option allow one to do pseudo-PUTs (something JSONP doesn't)?

Answer (score -2):

firstly this is a json question and u have tagged jquery...

if you need jquery then ... look up load() function.

$('#selector').load(ajaxURL);
alert($('#selector').html())

Comment: What you state is simply wrong. He clearly uses jQuery which can be seen from his use of `$.getJSON`. `load` is also definitely the wrong function for what he wants. So this question is tagged correctly only json is missing as tag