# Starting a couchdb DB in a HTML + Javascript web

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb

I have a website built with HTML and JavaScript, served by Tomcat.

I need to add a no-SQL database to it, and I'm trying Couch DB. I'm in trouble, 'cause I understand how the DB works, but I have no idea how to connect it with my website.

I'm used to SQL, where I just have to make a connection and then send SQL queries. How can I instantiate a connection object to CouchDB, and use couchdb.js? Currently, Tomcat answers me with a cross domain issue, 'cause Tomcat and couchdb are on different ports.

Can anybody help me with the very basics?

Comment: CouchDB exposes a REST API to manipulate the data. So all you have to do is making HTTP requests, which you typically do via Ajax in JS.

Comment: I know, and I'm trying to use couch.js which seems to have all the functions I need to add or consult information from my bd. The problem is that tomcat answers me with a cross domain issue, 'cause Tomcat and couchdb are in different ports... any help ???   And thank you for the interest :)

Comment: You can enable cross-domain access in the couchdb settings.http://stackoverflow.com/a/4090543/218196

Comment: Are you sure this is Tomcat that sends a cross-domain issue?!? Isn't it your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) [will be implemented](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CORS) only in the next release of CouchDB (v.1.3).

It could be surprising but one should realize that it is not the "very basics" of CouchDB:

1. Most of CouchApp web apps developers serve their Ajax applications from CouchDB itself (using HTML shows, lists, and attached static pages).
2. Some developers use CouchDB as a simple database within a 3-tier architecture.
3. Others send requests to CouchDB from desktop or signed applications (Java, Flash, etc.).

So, sending Ajax queries from code retrieved from external sites was relatively rare.

My recommended advice would be to adopt one of the most common settings.

If it is definitely not suited to your case, then you can either test CouchDB's development version, or use a proxy so that CouchDB appears to be on the same server as your HTML code (until the next release).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get familiar with curl, then you start to test your couchdb through command line.
Trying on the same machine that you installed couchdb.

```
$ curl localhost:5984
```

After that, try to access from a different machine using curl:

```
$ curl http://<your_couchdb_server_name_or_ip>:5984/
```

If you can't, you need to check if your server has a firewall that are blocking outside requests to your server on 5984 port.

Now, to access your couchdb from a ajax request you must configure the local.ini file:

```
[httpd]
enable_cors:true;

[cors]
credentials:true;
mehods:PUT,GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS;
origins:*;
```

Restart your couchdb and try again, this must fix you problem.